# Requested Node Engine Version Rejected by Heroku / Git

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

I'm following this basic tutorial to set up my node.js app on Heroku. when I do $ git push heroku master, the terminal responds with this answer:

-----> Resolving engine versions
 !     Requested engine node version 0.10.17 does not match available versions: 0.10.15 0.10.14 0.10.13 0.10.12 0.10.11 0.10.10 0.10.9 0.10.8 0.10.6 0.10.5 0.10.4 0.10.3 0.10.2 0.10.1 0.10.0 0.8.25 0.8.24 0.8.23 0.8.22 0.8.21 0.8.19 0.8.14 0.8.13 0.8.12 0.8.11 0.8.10 0.8.8 0.8.7 0.8.6 0.8.5 0.8.4 0.8.3 0.8.2 0.8.1 0.8.0 0.6.20 0.6.18 0.6.17 0.6.16 0.6.15 0.6.14 0.6.13 0.6.12 0.6.11 0.6.10 0.6.8 0.6.7 0.6.6 0.6.5 0.6.3 0.4.10 0.4.7

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

I have also already added "node": "0.10.17" and "npm": "1.3.9" to my package.json file

I am obviously using 0.10.17 but it doesnt seem to be supported by Heroku/Git. Any suggestions? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Any reason you can't use 0.10.15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to this is unless you have a hard dependency of a bug fix between `0.10.15` and `0.10.17` to simply dial your package.json back down to `0.10.15` or even `0.10` and that way Heroku will select the latest `0.10.*` version it supports.